# How to turn wifi on using ADB or any other way when usb debugging is disabled

Tags: android, adb

When Android is locked after Too many pattern attempts, it will ask you to sign in with your Google Account to unlock, I have my username and password but the mobile data and the wireless are not enabled and i can't enable it because it's totally locked, i don't want to make a factory reset because i will lose my data.

as a programmer I have wasted two days searching on how and i have found an answer using the ADB to turn on the wifi :

```
adb shell
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
update secure set value=1 where name='wifi_on';
.exit
```

However,it will not work if the USB debugging was disabled, Is there any other solution to enable the USB debugging on using ADB or to get the wifi or the mobile data on?

Please don't close this questions because Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development, because this question is related to software development, at lease please Android experts, Answer me and answer thousands of people who losing their data everyday, because Android is not turning the wireless on by default if it's locked or gives at least the opportunity to log in and unlock by storing the password locally. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: I think you'd have better luck at http://www.android.stackexchange.com

Comment: yep this has actually been covered over there already. There a bunch of great suggestions in the Answer here: [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/cannot-unlock-tablet-as-have-no-internet-connection) if those don't work I am guessing your only out is reset.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other solution to enable the USB debugging on using ADB or to get the wifi or the mobile data on?

No you can't do *anything* with ADB if USB debugging is turned off... That setting must be on in order to execute any ADB commands.

Comment: Not only that, on more recent versions, the particular development machine must have a certificate for ADB which has been whitelisted by user interaction on the unlocked device.

Comment: Then why Android isn't authorize using the Google mail password which is already stored locally? it's not logical to give people an incomplete solution to unlock, right? Either your luck was good and internet was ready or go to hell and loose everything, this really drive many people crazy.

Comment: @Ala I agree with you, but unfortunately google doesn't consult with me before they make decisions like this. Did you try everything in the android stackexchange link?

Comment: @FoamyGuy, Thanks for your answer, non of the solutions worked for me, I am using HTC One X, Do you have any solution to get a backup before doing the factory reset?

Answer (score 2):

If your device has been rooted, you can get adb shell by reboot your device into recovery mode, where USB Debugging is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that problem happened with me right now. I was almost recovering my smartphone but I found out a way to turn on wifi or 3g without using adb (no debug mode is necessary). I dont know if works with any phone (I did it at LG's phone). Lets go: just put the usb cable at phone-pc. At the screen to access phone as a storage device click yes and the droid (android avatar(?)) changes the colour (orange). When in storage mode is on, you can accessing the top bar to turn on/off some features like wifi/3g etc (a implementation security problem or a not correct security specification?). I help this information be usefull

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you will not lose any data. First of all, open your recovery menu, select "backup user data", and then reset your phone to factory setting, and then restore phone backup from same menu. Done. No data loss will take place, all apps will be there.